# use of 2 relative pronouns

Tags: relative-pronouns

> It was that which made him decide to resign that summer,when he was sixty five.

I could not understand why the writer used both relative pronouns (that,which) together?

Comment: But "that" is not a relative pronoun. It is a pro-form here referring to something previously mentioned. The only relative pronoun is "which", which is anaphoric to the pro-form "that", the antecedent.

Comment: Giving context and giving sources helps getting answers. Your sentence is from [*Good-bye, Mr. Chips*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks05/0500111.txt).

Answer (score 6):

**That** is not a relative pronoun in this sentence, it is a demonstrative pronoun. It refers to a fact that has just been stated. Let's look at the preceding sentence:

> In 1913 Chips had had bronchitis and was off duty for nearly the
>   whole of the winter term.  It was that which made him decide to
>   resign that summer, when he was sixty-five.

"That" replaces the whole preceding sentence.

You could rephrase the sentence as:

> The fact that he had had bronchitis in 1913 and was off duty for nearly the
>   whole of the winter term made Chips decide to resign that summer.

**Which** is the only relative pronoun in the sentence you quoted and it refers to **that**.